# Conda not seeing installed modules

Tags: python, debugging, module, conda-forge

For example, I just installed opencv using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Yet, when I go to run my program, I get a ModuleNotFoundError. I am using Wingpro. The python executable I give is to the activated environment:

```
C:\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat cf
```

Is it possible that I have to find and activate these modules that I have installed?

Comment: What is `cf` doing after the .bat? Usually you activate the environment then try accessing it after that. Also, you need to activate environment before installing packages if you want them in the environment. [managing conda envs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: I removed the cf and now all is well. That was placed there by the IDE (wingpro) I'm using. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never heard of that one. If you need a free alternative, there is PyCharm. But, I've heard this advice a lot: don't use an IDE if you're learning. The IDEs do too many things for you that need to be understood first. A good text editor is VS Code if you chose not to use an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem specific to Wingpro (a python IDE). I fixed this problem by setting my path correctly in wingpro. If you encounter this problem, go to project properties. Once there, insert the path to your bin. In my case, I directed the path to \Anaconda3\condabin.